# Add different configuration of mate as a new desktop environment

Tags: desktop-environments, mate, appearance

I'm setting up public Ubuntu computers for my school and I'd like to make it so that the user can choose what the mate desktop will look like when logging in, like when choosing which DE to use.

I'd like to set up one where the panel is at the bottom like on Windows, one that looks like mac os and one that I like. Is this possible somehow?

I'd like to preconfigure them and users should be able to choose between the configurations using the login manager as they can with different DEs. Users can of course change their personal configurations, but having a few preconfigured ones would be nice. Forking mate sounds like more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

I do something like this using dconf.

I configure a desktop -- theme, wallpaper, shortcuts, position of panels, content of panels -- apps, widgets, and so on. Then :

```
dconf dump / > dconf.desktop.1.out
```

I can then recreate that desktop on another computer or for another user with :

```
dconf load / < dconf.desktop.1.out
```

With a simple script you could rig up a menu of options from which your users could select a template and even create desktops of their own.